# Is it fair use to use figures from ArXiv preprints on Wikipedia?

Tags: uses-of-open-data, images, wikipedia, academia

Apologies if this isn't the right exchange. I'm not sure where this question should live.

There are some science figures from Arxiv papers that I think would greatly enhance a Wikipedia page on the subject the papers deal with. I'm curious on the copyright of using these images for this purpose.

To upload to ArXiv, the submitter agrees to one of the following:

- > grant arXiv.org a non-exclusive and irrevocable license to distribute the article, and certify that he/she has the right to grant this license;
- > certify that the work is available under one of the following Creative Commons licenses and that he/she has the right to assign this license:
  >   Creative Commons Attribution license (CC BY 4.0)
  >   Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike license (CC BY-SA 4.0)
  >   Creative Commons Attribution-Noncommercial-ShareAlike license (CC BY-NC-SA 4.0);
- > or dedicate the work to the public domain by associating the Creative Commons Public Domain Dedication (CC0 1.0) with the submission.

It's my impression that there are only doubts about screenshots from an article in the first category above. Is it within fair use to use figures from Arxiv preprints on Wikipedia or some other non-commercial, educational platform?

If articles need to be taken on a case-by-base basis, how do you go about finding out if one can use the article's figures?

---

[ArXiv license policy](https://arxiv.org/help/license)

Comment: what about sending an email to the first author(s if more than one) of the paper and ask for permission? also consider that using their images in a wiki related to the paper's topic, in my opinion, adds value to the paper itself.

Comment: CC BY-NC-SA content cannot be used on Wikipedia either (except by some non-license-specific mechanism such as claiming fair use or getting permission from the author).